# Why is this a multiple of $s$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $G$ a finite cyclic group of ordern $n=q_1^{a_1} \cdots q_t^{a_t}$,  $g\in G$. If $g^{\frac{n}{q_j}}\neq 1$ then $q_j^{a_j}\mid ord(g)$.

Proof:

Let $s=ord(g)$.

Then $s$ is a divisor of $n$, so it is of the form $s=q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_t^{b_t}$ with $0\leq b_i\leq a_i$ for $1\leq i\leq t$. 
We suppose that $q_j^{a_j}$ does nof divide $s$.

That means that $b_j\leq a_j-1$.

But then $$\frac{n}{q_j}=q_1^{a_1}\cdots q_{j-1}^{a_{j-1}}q_j^{a_j-1}q_{j+1}^{a_j+1}\cdots q_t^{a_t}$$ 
which is a multiple of $s$. 
So $g^{\frac{n}{q_j}}=1$, contradiction.

Could you explain to me why $$\frac{n}{q_j}=q_1^{a_1}\cdots q_{j-1}^{a_{j-1}}q_j^{a_j-1}q_{j+1}^{a_j+1}\cdots q_t^{a_t}$$ is a multiple of $s$??

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{n}{q_j} = q_1^{a_1}\cdots q_{j-1}^{a_{j-1}}q_j^{a_j-1}q_{j+1}^{a_j+1}$$ and thus this is a multiple of $s = q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_t^{b_t}$ because in $\frac{n}{q_j}$ the exponent of $q_i$ is greater than or equal to the corresponding exponent of $q_i$ in $s$ for all $i$.